# how to handle double click event each time in jquery

Tags: jquery

I create table dynamically included some data. when a user double click on each `<td>`, the `<td>` convert to `<input type='text'>`. if user clicks outside of this input, it must be saved to database.
but the problem is, if the user double clicks on the `<td>` , function triggered just for the first time and if double clicks again, it triggers on click event.

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td data-name="name">US</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script>
  $(document).on('dblclick','tbody tr td', function(){
    var value = $(this).text();
    var name = $(this).attr('data-name');
    $(this).html('<input type="text" id="tmp_ed" value="'+value+'"/>');
    $(document).on('click', function(e){
       if(e.target.id !='tmp_ed'){
          var item = $('#tmp_ed').val();
          $.ajax({
            url: "update.php",
            data: item,
            success: function(d){
               alert(d);
             }
          });
        }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: when user double click he gets `input` field, and if double click happens again script also creates new `input` , is that your problem?

Comment: @KresimirPendic. no . first just one time dblclick event fired. second is when user click anywhere inside document , onclick event fired. I want just out of `id='tmp_ed'` occur

Answer (score 0):

Yes this should be the behaviour. As you have attached the double click here -

```
 $(document).on('dblclick','tbody tr td', function(){
```

only to `tbody tr td` . Once you have clicked on it, it gets converted to `<input type='text'>` as you say. Now, this element does not have a double click attached to it. Hence you are not able to double click again.

If you need to have the double click again, modify the JS to -

```
        ....
        var name = $(this).attr('data-name');
        $(this).html('<input type="text" id="tmp_ed" value="'+value+'"/>');
        $(this).on('dblclick', function(){
            $(this).html(value);    
        })    
        $(document).on('click', function(e){
           if(e.target.id !='tmp_ed'){
        ....
```

Refer fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/jmeengzu/

Comment: how can I handle it?

Comment: If you want to double click again, you will have to attach double click listener to the new element as well i.e - `<input type='text'>`

Comment: Updating the answer to achieve double click on the text as well. Try it.

Comment: @but as I said the tr are created by ajax call after loading the page

Comment: So is this not the exact HTML you are working on?.. Please share the complete code maybe on fiddle.  If I understand, you want to attach the double click with the dynamically created `tr` as well. Is it? In that case you need to call `$(document).on('dblclick','tbody tr td', function(){' after page is loaded as this would attach the listener to only those `'tbody tr td'` that are available when this is being called. And the tr created after the AJAX call would be left behind.

Answer (score 0):

```
isSingleClick: Boolean = true;     

method1CallForClick(){
   this.isSingleClick = true;
        settimeout(()=>{
            if(this.isSingleClick){
                 doTheStuffHere();
            }
         },250)
}
method2CallForDblClick(){
         this.isSingleClick = false;
         doTheStuffDblClickHere();
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you can provide a description of your answer. Code-only answers are sometimes less helpful than those with a brief description.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how the code answers the question improves its long-term value. It also helps avoid having your answer down-voted or flagged as low quality. See [How to Write a Good Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).